# Is DPF removal on Australian diesels legal

Tags: australia, vehicle

I have a second hand 2010 Subaru Outback that is having major DPF issues, I have been trying to get a definitive answer if it is legal to remove the DPF according to current emissions standards in Australia NSW.

The document I am referring to is:
https://infrastructure.gov.au/roads/environment/files/Emission_Limits_for_Light_Vehicles_Euro_2_Euro_6.pdf

This document has a footnote regarding compression ignition diesel engines which contains the following:

> The “core” Euro 5 requirements which apply in ADR79/03 require
>   compliance with all the technical requirements of UN Regulation 83/06
>   except that ADR79/03:
>
> - allows the provision of PM mass emissions data based on the previous UN R83/05 (Annex 4) Type I test procedure (with a PM mass
>     emissions limit of 0.005g/km) in lieu of data collected under the
>     revised test procedure (Annex 4a of UN R83/06) which specifies a limit
>     of 0.0045g/km);
> - accepts a relaxed OBD threshold limit (80mg/km) for PM mass for M and N category vehicles of reference mass >1760kg;
> - **does not require compliance with the PM number limit specified for diesel vehicles in UN R83/06;**
> - does not require compliance with the In Use Performance Ratio for OBD systems in UN R83/06;
> - does not require the NOx monitoring for petrol vehicles specified in UN R83/06; and
> - only requires flex fuel vehicles to meet the Type VI test when tested on petrol (details of requirements for flex fuel vehicles to
>     meet the Type VI test under ADR79/04 and ADR79/05 at low temperature
>     to be determined by 31 December 2011).

Since my car was manufactured in 2010 I am unable to determine if this regulation exception applies to my vehicle.

Comment: This might be a matter of state / territory law or regulation.  Which state / territory are you in?

Comment: Sorry about that, it is NSW, I have also udpated the question.